# Forward to another sonata admin controller

Tags: php, sonata-admin, symfony-2.3

I have custom action in sonata admin controller.

I need forwarding to another sonata admin controller.

Is it possible?

When I try next:

```
return $this->forward("DemoBundle:AnotherAdmin:doSomething", array('id' => $id));
```

next error is shown:

```
There is no `_sonata_admin` defined for the controller `DemoBundle\Controller\AnotherAdminController` and the current route ``
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've fixed my issue.

```
return $this->forward("DemoBundle:AnotherAdmin:doSomething", array('id' => $id, '_sonata_admin' => $this->container->get('request')->get('_sonata_admin')));
```

Answer (score 0):

Nice! But in my case I had to do the following to get the '`_sonata_admin`' value:

```
$this->getRequest()->get('_sonata_admin')]
```

Answer (score 0):

I have solved this Problem with:

```
$request->request->set('_sonata_admin','admin.template');
```